# SQL Covering Columns Order

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does the order of covering columns matter in an index?

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON MyTable (Col1, Col2) INCLUDE (Col3, Col4)
```

That is the order of Col3 & Col4 in the above example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, included columns are not ordered, so the order that they appear does not matter